# Jmeter WebDriver Sampler fails to map List<WebElement> to driver.findElements(locator) method

Tags: java, list, plugins, jmeter

- Jmeter version 4.0 r1823414,
- Selenium/WebDriver Support plugin version 2.3,
- java version 1.8.0_161.

While working with the *Jmeter WebDriver* sampler I was really impressed by the things it can do (quickly creating scripts for UI / performance testing). However, I wasn't able to utilize `List` (from `java.util`) interface while locating several web elements on the page. I did, as it was suggested in every *WebDriver* plugin tutorials, imported necessary namespaces `java.util.*;` and `java.lang.util.*;`.

In the Log Viewer there is an error

> messageERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: In file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.util.*; import java.lang.*; import org.openqa.selenium.*; import org . . . '' Encountered "=" at line 57, column 38.

where my line 57 looks like this

```
List<WebElement> deleteLinks = WDS.browser.findElements(By.xpath("${myEnumeratorDeclaredVariable}"));
```

According to [Selenium docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/) method `findElements(By by)` has a signature of `java.util.List<WebElement>` My question today is: is there any specifically designed limitations with the WebDriver sampler plugin that prohibits of using some interfaces and classes from the native Java world?

Can I, as usual, create classes and methods inside the sampler? Please advise of someone as well interfered with these problems before.

**P.S.** Dmitri T answer was accepted. Please read comments below his response. If you are planning to use Java as your programming language for WebDriver sampler, be advised that it's a BeanShell interpretation of the Java, not the vanilla Java itself. For more modern features of the language (versions 6,7 and 8) please switch to groovy as an option as it supports 99% of the modern Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what language you're using:

1. In case of default JavaScript you need to use JavaScript syntax like:

   ```
   var deleteLinks = WDS.browser.findElements(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("${myEnumeratorDeclaredVariable}"));
   ```

   Demo:

   [image: JMeter WebDriver JavaScript]
2. In case of Java you don't get "vanilla" Java, you get [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/) interpreter which doesn't support the [diamond operator](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2074080/core-java/jdk-7--the-diamond-operator.html) so you need to remove it like:

   ```
   List deleteLinks = WDS.browser.findElements(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("${myEnumeratorDeclaredVariable}"));
   ```

   [image: JMeter Java Iterate Links]
3. Don't reference JMeter functions and/or variables in script like `"${myEnumeratorDeclaredVariable}"`, go for `WDS.vars` instead like:

   ```
   List deleteLinks = WDS.browser.findElements(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath(WDS.vars.get("myEnumeratorDeclaredVariable")));
   ```

More information: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, I was confused on the http://www.beanshell.org/manual/quickstart.html#Java_Statements_and_Expressions it says "BeanShell understands standard Java statements, expressions, and method declarations. Statements and expressions are all of the normal things that you'd say inside a Java method such as variable declarations and assignments, method calls, loops, and conditionals." So I suspect I can easily use diamond operator as well as loops. But seems like neither of them are utilizable in WebDriver sampler script window.

Comment: Beanshell was released in 2005 so it supports pretty much everything from **Java SE 5.0**. Diamond operator was introduced in Java 7 in 2011 so it is not supported in Beanshell. If you want to use modern Java features consider switching to [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) which fully supports underlying JVM syntax and has its [own enhancements](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/) on top

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for the support. From https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black those lines "valid Java code in 99% of cases will be valid Groovy code". Does that mean I can literally create classes and methods inside the WebDriver sampler?

Comment: I probably underestimated Groovy as an option as I thought that this is a completely different programming language that would normally require a time to get familiar with. Thanks for the support Dmitri.

Comment: as you suggested, I selected script language type as Groovy in Jmeter, created a class with the bunch of methods, and while trying to run it getting "WebDriverSampler: unknown protocol: data" error message. My class structure is the typical Java class with import statements on top, class declaration little below, class fields declarations, and methods as usual. Do you have an idea what this error message might mean? Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

If you use last version of Webdriver Sampler you need to select Groovy to be able to use the syntax you’re using.

Otherwise, by default it will use Javascript Rhino.

If issue persists, please show all your code.